# In a VS Report Server Project can I retrieve and save Parameter values?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

We have a company website where BI reports are hosted.  For one particular report (and possibly for others, if this can be made to work), there is a requirement to:

a) retrieve saved values for report parameters

and

b) to save any changed values for report parameters

I know that parameter values can be retrieved from data by setting the Default Values to "Get values from a query".

However, what I would like to do is when the user presses **View Report** that the values that [s]he has selected should be saved to a database so that these will then form the default values for the next user.

Can this be done?  There doesn't seem to be any way "out of the box".

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple.

Lets assume you had a table of Countries that drive your parameter's available values and that this table `myCountryTable` has two columns `CountryID` and `CountryName`.

You available values dataset would be something simple like

```
SELECT * FROM myCountryTable
```

`CountryID` would be the parameter value and `CountryName` would be the parameter label.

OK so you will have probably done all the above already.

Now, in your main dataset query simply add an `INSERT` statement before you main query runs.

So, if you dataset query looks like this..

```
SELECT * FROM SomeBigTable WHERE CountryID in (@CountryID)
```

you would change it to something like

```
INSERT INTO myLogTable
    SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM myCountryTable WHERE CountryID IN (@CountryID)
-- original query follows
SELECT * FROM SomeBigTable WHERE CountryID in (@CountryID)
```

**Note**: If you cannot change your main dataset query for whatever reason, you can do this in a separate dataset but there are a few things you will have to do

First: Change the sql so that it returns a value at the end, anything will do e.g.

```
INSERT INTO myLogTable
   SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM myCountryTable WHERE CountryID IN (@CountryID)
   SELECT 1 as myReturnValue
```

Second: You must bind this dataset to something on the report such as a table or list, this is to make sure the query only executes when the report is executed, not when parameters are changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could store parameters and their values every time the report is executed.

***Note***: Some of these integrated SQL functions maybe do not exist on your server, which depends on the server version. If that is the case, it is easy to find alternative, or even create your own function.

For example, at the end of every stored procedure that is used by report place this part of SQL query that uses newly created table `dbo.ReportParameterValuePairs`:

`INSERT INTO dbo.ReportParameterValuePairs
(ReportName, ParameterValuePair, ExecutionDateTime)
VALUES(
'MyReport',
'$$$parameter1$$$: ' + @parameter1 + ',' +
'$$$parameter2$$$: ' + @parameter2,
GETDATE())`

Later on will be clear why are these data stored and why in this way.

Nest step would be creating procedure which will retrieve value of some parameter during the last execution of report:

`CREATE PROCEDURE spRetrieveReportParameterValue
    @parameter NVARCHAR(100),
    @report NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN`

```
-- this is an example
DECLARE @parameters NVARCHAR(MAX) = '$$$parameter1$$$: value1, $$$parameter2$$$: value2'
-- in reality parameter-value pairs will be retrieved from database
--DECLARE @parameters NVARCHAR(MAX) =
--  (SELECT TOP 1 ParameterValuePair
--  FROM dbo.ReportParameterValuePairs
--  WHERE ReportName = @report
--  ORDER BY ExecutionDateTime DESC)

--SELECT @parameters

DECLARE @parameterValuePair NVARCHAR(200) =
    (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@parameters, ',')
    WHERE
        VALUE LIKE '%$$$' + @parameter + '$$$%')

--SELECT @parameterValuePair

DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(100) =
(SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@parameterValuePair, ':') WHERE value NOT LIKE '%$$$%')

SELECT TRIM(@value) AS ParameterValue
```

`END`

Parameters of the procedure are: parameter which value is needed, report that is executing.

Parameter-value pairs are stored in a single string. To access that data search table `dbo.ReportParameterValuePairs` for currently executing report. Order data by date and time of execution, starting from the latest.

Parameter-value pairs string will be split using `,`. The result of this split is a table that consists of parameter-value pairs. Distinction between parameters and their values is `$$$` mark. Because of that the condition in query is `VALUE LIKE '%$$$' + @parameter + '$$$%'`.
Variable `@parameterValuePair` now stores desired parameter and its value.

After another one split, this time using `:` because it separates value from parameter name, the result of split will be two rows. One contains parameter and $$$ marks (*$$$[parameter]$$$*) and the other contains the value. Using condition `WHERE value NOT LIKE '%$$$%'` parameter's value will be stored to `@value` variable.

Last step of the procedure is to trim the value in case there are empty spaces at the end and at the beginning of the `@value` and return it as `ParameterValue`.

In order to retrieve this value to report create *DataSet* for every report parameter. This DataSet will supply parameter with default value:

1. right click on *DataSets*
2. choose *Add Dataset*
3. choose tab/card *Query*
4. name *DataSet*
5. select *Data source*
6. for query type choose *Text*
7. enter `spRetrieveReportParameterValue 'parameter1', 'MyReport'` where `parameter1` is name of parameter which last value will be retrieved
8. click *Refresh Fields*

[image]

The last step is to set default value to the parameter:

1. right click on parameter
2. select *Parameter Properties*
3. choose card/tab *Default Values*
4. choose option *Get values from a query*
5. for *Dataset* choose newly created dataset
6. for Value field choose *ParameterValue*

[image]

This should be the result:

[image]